# BulletPhysics (ammo.js) - How would you go about applying force to an object?

Tags: javascript, bullet

To clarify - `ammo.js` is a port of Bullet Physics using mscripten

I have a character (essentially a block) that needs to be pushed with force. I have tried (I think) all of the methods for forces but I still cannot move the block.

`setVelocity(1,0,0)` does not even move the block - it just stops gravity from acting on it!
`applyImpulse([0,0,200000],[0,0,0])` does absolutely nothing.
`applyForce([0,0,200000],[0,0,0])` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: For future reference, surround inline code with ` (the thing next to the number 1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the fact that ammo.js is an emscripten port, you have to use its native datatypes to talk to it...

So for setting velocity you'd need to body.setLinearVelocity(new Ammo.btVector3(1,0,0));

Same goes for applyForce and applyImpulse.

In my code, I usually make a set of temporary btVector3s, and use them throughout the file, in order to reduce the overhead of allocation and garbage collection..

```
var tbv30 = new Ammo.btVector3();

function setBodyVelocity(body,x,y,z){
    tbv30.setValue(x,y,z);
    body.setLinearVelocity(tbv30);
}
```

good luck :D

Comment: Not sure I follow, @Funkodebat ?

Comment: well... assuming all you want to do is reuse the vector.. then you'd want `function doSomeStuff(body, x, y, z) {  ... }` so you can actually use your own values instead of 10,0,0 every time.

Comment: Note for beginners: if body.setLinearVelocity() is not doing anything, the body might be deactivated. Call body.activate() before body.setLinearVelocity().